# REST API in Python with FastAPI and pydantic: read-only property in model

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, fastapi, pydantic

Assume a REST API which defines a POST method on a resource /foos to create a new Foo. When creating a Foo the name of the Foo is an input parameter (present in the request body). When the server creates a Foo it assigns it an ID. This ID is returned together with the name in the REST response.
I am looking for something similar to readOnly in OpenAPI.

The input JSON should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "bar"
}
```

The output JSON should look like that:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "bar"
}
```

Is there a way to reuse the same pydantic model? Or is it necessary to use two diffent models?

```
class FooIn(BaseModel):
    name: str

class Foo(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
```

I cannot find any mentions of "read only", "read-only", or "readonly" in the pydantic documentation or in the Field class code.

Googling I found a post which mentions

```
id: int = Schema(..., readonly=True)
```

But that seems to have no effect in my use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is fine to have multiple models. You can use inheritance to reduce code  repetition:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


# Properties to receive via API create/update
class Foo(BaseModel):
    name: str


# Properties to return via API
class FooDB(Foo):
    id: int
```

The [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/) *which is excellent btw!*, goes into this more in-depth.

[Here](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/schemas/user.py) is a real user model example taken from the official full stack project generator.  You can see how there are multiple models to define the user schema depending on the context.